# What does a PHP function return by default?

Tags: php, function, variables, language-design

If I return nothing explicitly, what does a php function exactly return?

```
function foo() {}
```

1. What type is it?
2. What value is it?
3. How do I test for it exactly with === ?
4. Did this change from php4 to php5?
5. Is there a difference between `function foo() {}` and `function foo() { return; }`

(I am not asking how to test it like `if (foo() !=0) ...`)

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php for official documentation

Answer (score 105, accepted):

1. `null`
2. `null`
3. `if(foo() === null)`
4. -
5. Nope.

You can try it out by doing:

```
$x = foo();
var_dump($x);
```

Comment: Note that this is not true when you are using types in PHP >=7.1. You would expect this to work if return type is `?string` but it will give error like `TypeError: Return value must be of type ?string, none returned`. In such cases you need to explicitly return null. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#122592

Answer (score 40):

Not returning a value from a PHP function has the same semantics as a function which returns null.

```
function foo() {}

$x=foo();

echo gettype($x)."\n";
echo isset($x)?"true\n":"false\n";
echo is_null($x)?"true\n":"false\n";
```

This will output

```
NULL
false
true
```

You get the same result if foo is replaced with

```
function foo() {return null;}
```

There has been no change in this behaviour from php4 to php5 to php7 (I just [tested](https://3v4l.org/UHCMA#tabs) to be sure!)

Comment: +1 but i wish i could +2, this is the more complete answer (includes question #4 regarding change in behavior between php versions)

Comment: *But* using type hinting for return value, you have to omit a `return null;` on `: void` but have to `return null;` on (for example) `: ?string` when no string is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I did find an oddity when specifying function return types. When you do, you must be explicit about returning something from your functions.

```
<?php

function errorNoReturnDeclared($a = 10) : ?string {
    if($a == 10) {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}

errorNoReturnDeclared(); //Fatal error
```

Error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Return value of errorNoReturnDeclared() must be of the type string or null, none returned in
```

So if you decide to add some return type specifications on old functions make sure you think about that.

Comment: You find it odd that you have to return anything when you explicitly said to PHP that you WILL return a string or null?

Comment: Well, if a function returns null by default, then I don't see why I should do it even if I'm declaring the return type. The compiler should deal with it.

Comment: This is actually confirmed behaviour. If there's no return on function, it will throw an error (PHP8.1)
```Return value must be of type ?string, none returned```