# Convention of setting return type in php boolean functions

Tags: php, performance, boolean, boolean-logic

Is it good to explicitly 'return FALSE' in a Boolean function or just 'return TRUE'

Example A:

```
  function check($link){
  if(isset($link)){
  return TRUE;
  }else{
  return FALSE;
  }
```

**OR**
Example B:

```
  function check($link){
  if(isset($link)){
  return TRUE;
  }
```

By default php functions return FALSE, so  is it good if I mention return FALSE or ignore it as Example B

so if im checking whether its true or false

```
 if(check('eqweqw')){
  echo 'its set';
 }else{
 echo 'its not';
 }
```

Comment: `By default php functions return FALSE` this is not true. If you dont return any value, you'll get `NULL`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218580/what-does-a-php-function-return-by-default

Comment: explicit is better than implicit, so I personally tend to say go with first one.

Comment: I think opinions will be split on this. I suspect the real answer is it depends on the merits of the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example A is better practice because it explicitly states the intention of your code. If someone reading your code doesn't know that FALSE is returned by default, they'll probably assume your code is buggy.

Remember: write code so it can be easily read and understood by others.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> Note: If no parameter is supplied, then the parentheses must be
>   omitted and NULL will be returned.

If you want your function to return `false`you have to explicit return a false. As null is not equal to false construct B wil fail in some cases:

```
if(check('eqweqw') === false){
 echo 'its not';
 }else{
  echo 'its set';
 }
```

Will return `its set` in construct B

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it would be better to return a boolean in all cases, rather than just `true` or nothing.

Here's how I would do it:

```
function check($link){

  $result = false;

  if(isset($link)){
     $result = true;
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Try to avoid having lots of points in your code where you `return`, and have a single exit point where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce it to:

```
function check($link){
  return isset($link);
}
```

But that sounds a lot like it's functionally equivalent to isset, so maybe you should just use that instead.  As for the best practices question, if PHP is returning bool true/false on isset it might be good for you to do the same.