# Return a Function in Wordpress Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Recently I have been playing around with Wordpress Shortcode. When following [this](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/) tutorial (changed a few things, of course), I found that even without returning anything (return $return_string; - part) my code is still working as intended.

I opened PHP manual and it says:

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call. return will also end the execution of
>   an eval() statement or script file.

My question:

Since looks like there is nothing broken, should I keep doing what I do, or should I "return" something from my function (there is actually a downside from not "return-ing" anything I just haven't seen, yet) ?

Edit: The code, just in case.. no "return", still processing the shortcode / loop

```
function looping_cat($atts, $content) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      "query" => '',
      "category" => ''
    ), $atts));

    $wp_query = new WP_Query();

    if(!empty($category)){
      $query .= '&category_name='.$category;
    }
    $wp_query->query($query);
    ?>

      <ul>
      <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
          <li>
              <div>
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                   <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
              </div>
               <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
              </div>
          </li>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
      </ul>
    <?php 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a `return` statement, `null` will be returned. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218580/what-does-a-php-function-return-by-default).

If it fits your goals that *nothing* will be displayed for your shortcode, it is fine to omit the `return` statement.

For readability purposes I recommend to use `return` statements everywhere, even if you are returning `null`.

**Edit:**

Now I understand what do you mean by *returning nothing*. Actually you're **inlining** the HTML in your shortcut function.

Actually, I still prefer to **collect and return** all content **as a string**, because it gives you more control of handling the content. If a certain condition happens later, you may still decide to return something else. It may also "disturb" WP, because inlining will output the content *immediately*, while returning the content enabled WP to decide when (and where) will it show.

Comment: Hmm.. I know this sound cliche "it works here".. but it actually is. I'm sure you know how WP shortcode works, my shortcode is to display loop from a certain category. A few minutes ago, I removed 1 letter from [shortcode] so it became [hortcode]. Refreshed the page, the loop disappear. Add the letter back, save and refreshed, and the loop is back. ..? I am **not** saying that you are wrong, but.. well, this is why I am asking the question.

Comment: Well, if you want to display something, you should *really* use `return`. It also improves readability (even for yourself after 1 week).

Comment: A shortcode shall not `print`/`echo` **anything**. It has to `return` something. Otherwise, it prints *before* `the_content`. Well, unless it's the desired effect.

Comment: @brasofilo WP has a mechanism for building the page. By `return`ing the content you use it (if you are using it properly). If not, the **behavior is unpredictable**. It may *seem* to work, but future versions of WP may **behave differently**, then OP will face a terrible refactoring.