# POST method Restful API codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-2

I try the rest api. When I use `GET` method, the code run. But when I use `POST` method the code return `false`.

Here is my **restclient controller**:

```
$this->load->spark('restclient/2.1.0');

$this->load->library('rest');

$this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'serverhere'));


$name=$this->input->post('name');
$params = array('name' => $name);
$uri = 'userscontroller/user';

$result = $this->rest->post($uri, $params,"json");
$this->rest->debug();
```

Here is my **restserver controller**:

```
public function name_get(){

$name=$this->get("name");

$this->response($name);

}

public function name_post(){

$name=array('name'=>$this->input->post("name"));
$this->response($name);

}
```

The `name_post` response is always `FALSE`. Help!

Comment: in my opinion is return false because it is default behavior of function. you not returning anything (zero, null, nada, 0) then you have got false. Modify your function to if statement and put something like this: if ( something ) { return true; } else {return false }, look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218580/what-does-a-php-function-return-by-default

Comment: $this->response($name); this one return the value..when I use get method the function return the value of $name...but when I use the post method..the function return false

Comment: because when you are use post method you call php interpreter and code above is running on server side and put empty HTML and this is why you have false ( null contenet = false ) in test put to your function [code] echo 'hello world'; [/code] and wrote is it something change