# PHP Functions - Should I always leave a return? (even when returning nothing)

Tags: php

What is the best practice for placing a return value in PHP function that doesn't need to return anything? Here I have two examples here.

*No Return*

```
function SayHello(){
    echo 'Hello';
}
```

*Return no value*

```
function SayHello(){
    echo 'Hello';
    return;
}
```

*Irrelevant...*

```
function SayHello(){
    echo 'Hello';
    return; // or no return; - It really doesn't matter, there is no standard
}
```

If there really is no rule of thumb here, could you please let me know what PSR standards have to say about this (if anything)?

I'm just trying to form good habits. If this is opinion based, could you not flag this question as 'opinion based' - but simply answer 'opinion based'?

Comment: Haven't seen anyone leaving empty returns (except coffeescript). since return type void was added to PHP 7.1 I'm sure it's ok. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean JimL. Which would be ok? Or best?

Comment: If you're using PHP 7.1 I would set the return type to void (for dev experience, ide auto completion/hinting and getting exceptions if the function is misused), but not have an actual return in the function. it serves no purpose

Comment: It's pointless noise to have an unnecessary `return;` statement. I'd think it was a typo/bug at first if I saw it in a PHP codebase.

Comment: Could anyone cite a standard such as PSR that defines it one way or another?

Comment: Until we cite a standard, I guess this is more of an opinion based answer. If you look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218580/what-does-a-php-function-return-by-default#answer-1218598 - You can see that it doesn't matter which way you handle it on a coding level. Thanks for the help though. I think I'll take ceejayoz advice and drop it for now.